# How to handle webview cache

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-webview

What I simply need is the possibility of loading webpage offline.

I read about `setAppCachePath` and all other related methods, but according the docs It deprected in API 30(https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings).

They recommended to use `Service Workers` instead.

I didn't find much info about it, how can I use this in order to load cache pages?

And other related question - if I have unknown amounts of webview page, Is it even good to save it to cache? cause the app can reach to huge size with let's say 1000 webviews in cache